# Create and use a custom terminology using AWS Translate API via POSTMAN

Tags: amazon-web-services

I would like to ask your help on how to create and use a custom terminology with AWS Translate by API. I'm using Postman to test, FYI.

I tried the action [ImportTerminology](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/translate/latest/APIReference/API_ImportTerminology.html) from the documentation.

Below is the headers in Postman (I'm not sure if *AWSShineFrontendService_20170701.ImportTerminology* is the correct value for **X-Amz-Target**).
[image: headers_postman_awstranslate].

Below is the Body in JSON format:
[image: Body_postman_awstranslate]

When sending the POST request, this is what I got as response :
[image: response_postman_awstranslate]

Please note that the request is successfull if I translate text simply using the API (using the value *AWSShineFrontendService_20170701.TranslateText* in the headers *X-Amz-Target*):
[image: response_simple_translate_post]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Best wishes,